# Subview transform changes when device is rotated

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform, image-rotation

I have added an `UIImageView` as a subview to a `containerView` of type UIView.
UIImageView have some transformations (scale and rotation). When I change device orientation then image's transformation also changes.

Before Rotation

[image]

After Rotation

[image]

How to fix this?

UPDATE: here is the transformation code

`code`
   func scale(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

```
    if gesture.numberOfTouches < 2 {
          return
    }
    if gesture.state == .began {
        lastScale = 1.0
        lastPoint = gesture.location(in: self)
    } else if gesture.state == .ended {
        adjustMinimumRect()
        return
    }

    // Scale
    let scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - gesture.scale)
    layer.setAffineTransform(layer.affineTransform().scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale))
    lastScale = gesture.scale

    // Translate
    let point = gesture.location(in: self)
    layer.setAffineTransform(layer.affineTransform().translatedBy(x: point.x - lastPoint.x,
                                                                  y: point.y - lastPoint.y))
    lastPoint = gesture.location(in: self)

}
```

Comment: are you using auto layout or manually setting frames?

Comment: How are your constraints setup?

Comment: I have settings frames programmatically and the subview has auto resizing mask setup                                                                                                                    self.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask.allMargins
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting. I find this editing tool not easy

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the transformation?

Comment: I have updated with scale. I am really thankful to everyone as you suggested it correctly, it was the constraint issue. I have got it fixed. Thanks everyone for your quick help!